# ajax return values not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update a feed when a user gets to the bottom of the page and add the new content. It for some reason is not returning the content at all.
Here is my jquery/javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 650){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("thumbs").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("thumbs").innerHTML = "Error Occurred.";
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "include/update-gamer-feed-curl.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    });
```

The php file already works because it gets the first ten items already and I am just calling it again to get the data to reload into the screen so I can prepare to append what is needed once I get more elements.

It is telling me the xmlhttp is depreciated. I have also tried using

```
$.ajax({url: "include/update-gamer-feed-curl.php", success: function(result)
{
 $("#thumbs").append(result);
}
```

but this doesnt work either. I know it is in this because if I put the string test in the append element where result is it appends the test string.

Comment: "It is telling me the xmlhttp is depreciated" — No, it is saying that synchronous requests are deprecated. Remove the third argument to open. Make an asynchronous request.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest isn't deprecated. Synchronous AJAX is deprecated, so you would get that warning if you used `false` as the third argument to `xmlhttp.open()`.

Comment: Check the Network tab of the Javascript console to see what the server is returning.

Comment: I removed the third argument the error went away but it is still not returning the elements.

Comment: what is the `xmlhttp.status`? Is it something that is not 200? what is the statusText.

Comment: In the network tab when it does the request it doesnt add anything too it. Just deletes the data. It is also not return an error on the status or the ready state.

Comment: doing this on scroll without debouncing seems like a really bad idea to me

Comment: what does `console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);` inside `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {}` tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
    $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 650){
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "/echo/json/", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("thumbs").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Error: rState=" + xmlhttp.readyState + ", status=" + xmlhttp.status);
                    }          
                }
            }
        }
    }, 250));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It seems the request is repeated too much. A timer of 250ms helped some, but still, the innerHTML is overwritten too fast. So I also change so that innerHTML is written to if success, but console gets the error. readyState 1,2,3 is repeated many many times when scrolling, and causes many errors. Avoided by checking readtState == 4 first.

Here are the description of the readystates

- 0=The current object is not initialized (the open method has not been
  called yet).
- 1=The request is opened, but the send method has not been called yet.
- 2=The request is sent but no data has been received yet.
- 3=A part of the data has been received, but it is not yet available.
- 4=All data is available.

Make sure readyState == 4 first, and then checks the status. And by moving open and send above onreadystatechange, you avoid readystate errors 0 and 1.

Comment: This does actually pull in the page like needed but when we call it it now says that the errors are rstate =1 status = 0, rstate=2 status = 200.

Comment: I updated my answer, it appears you have to check readystate == 4 first, then check for the status.

Comment: If you feel I solved your original question, please remember to mark the answer as soon as you're able. :) Thanks

Comment: I think we are close I feel you have provided me with the right answer i think the problem now is within the file I am calling. I will have to look at the api and other calls in that file to see why its not wanting to load the data. thank you for your time and answer.